# How to calculate time overlapping in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want o find overlapped time slot with small code. Lets there are time slots:

```
const slots = [
    {
    start_time: '10:30',
    end_time: '11:00'
  },
  {
    start_time: '11:30',
    end_time: '12:00'
  }
]
```

And I got the value from user as:

```
const inputStartTime = '10:50';
const inputEndTime = '11:20';
```

I think, there will be no overlapping if `inputStartTime > slots.end_time` and `inputEndTime < slots.start_time`. So, I want to set a variable such as const `overlappedSlots = //` and get the output of that variable as (`console.log(overlappedSlots)`):

```
[{
  start_time: "10:30",
  end_time: "11:00"
}]
```

But, I can't get this output by writing this function:

```js
const inputStartTime = '10:50';
const inputEndTime = '11:20';

const slots = [
    {
    start_time: '10:30',
    end_time: '11:00'
  },
  {
    start_time: '11:30',
    end_time: '12:00'
  }
]

const overlappedSlots = slots.filter(slot => !slot.end_time < inputStartTime || !slot.start_time > inputEndTime);
console.log(overlappedSlots)
```

What I was doing wrong there?

Comment: Lots of issues with your code. I'd recommend dateFns or momentJS to handle times though

Answer (score 0):

The error is when you use `!` without parenthesis

```js
const inputStartTime = '10:50';
const inputEndTime = '11:20';

const slots = [{
    start_time: '10:30',
    end_time: '11:00',
  },
  {
    start_time: '11:30',
    end_time: '12:00',
  },
];

const overlappedSlots = slots.filter(
  (slot) => inputStartTime > slot.start_time || !(slot.start_time > inputEndTime));
console.log(overlappedSlots);
```

Comment: OPPS! Thanks for finding it out. But, the `overlappedSlots` is one object: `[{
  start_time: "10:30",
  end_time: "11:00"
}]`. But, at here, we are getting two objects in the output. Is there any other issue in the logic?

Comment: My question is, why would you do `!(slot.end_time < inputStartTime)` when it is the same thing as `slot.end_time > inputStartTime`

Comment: what happens if the `inputStartTime: 09:00`, `inputEndTime: 10:00` or `inputStartTime: 15:00`, `inputEndTime: 16:00`? I tried to find out valid time (Not overlapping time) slot at first. I thought the valid time slot is when there is `inputStartTime > slots.end_time` and `inputEndTime < slots.start_time` . So, I want to filter out those which is not matching the (valid/not overlapping time slot) condition. Thats why, I have used `!`.

Comment: I just edited my post

Comment: Not working as expected if I change into this: `const inputStartTime = '11:50';
const inputEndTime = '12:20';`

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code remains with  `!`
Try this :

```
const overlappedSlots = slots.filter(slot => !(slot.end_time < inputStartTime) || !(slot.start_time > inputEndTime));

    console.log("over"+overlappedSlots);
```

Comment: But, the `overlappedSlots` is one object: [{   start_time: "10:30",   end_time: "11:00" }]. But, at here, we are getting two objects in the output. Is there any other issue in the logic?

Comment: it's only one object for me

Comment: Here is the output: https://jsfiddle.net/unz14a8d/

Answer (score 0):

use `&&` instead of  `||`
this will give you the result you want
**time start : 10:30 end time: 11:00**

Comment: Not getting the expected output if I change into this: `const inputStartTime = '11:50';
const inputEndTime = '12:20';`. In that case, I should get the output as: `{
    start_time: '11:30',
    end_time: '12:00'
  }` But, I am getting the two objects

Answer (score 0):

> I think, there will be no overlapping if `inputStartTime > slots.end_time` and `inputEndTime < slots.start_time`.

I'm not sure that's right, I *think* there would be no overlapping if `inputStartTime >= slots.end_time` **or** `inputEndTime <= slots.start_time`; the negation of which would look like:

```
!(inputStartTime >= slot.end_time || inputEndTime <= slot.start_time)
```

which would be the same as

```
!(inputStartTime >= slot.end_time) && !(inputEndTime <= slot.start_time)
```

which would be the same as

```
slot.end_time > inputStartTime && slot.start_time < inputEndTime
```

```js
const slots = [
  { start_time: '10:30', end_time: '11:00' },
  { start_time: '11:30', end_time: '12:00' },
  { start_time: '12:00', end_time: '12:30' },
  { start_time: '12:30', end_time: '13:00' },
];

const minutes = (hm) => {
  const [h, m] = hm.split(':').map((x) => +x);
  return h * 60 + m;
};

const overlapping_slots = (slots, start, end) =>
  slots.filter(
    (slot) => (
      minutes(slot.end_time) > minutes(start) &&
      minutes(slot.start_time) < minutes(end)
    )
  );

console.log(overlapping_slots(slots, '10:50', '11:20'));
console.log(overlapping_slots(slots, '11:50', '12:20'));
console.log(overlapping_slots(slots, '12:00', '12:30'));
console.log(overlapping_slots(slots, '9:30', '13:00'));
```